# Percentile(s) - logical explanation

Tags: mean, quantiles, percentage, types-of-averages

What EXACTLY do percentiles (/does which) mean, how are they distributed exactly (equally/weighed)?

Comment: The 50th percentile is the median. It need not in general be either halfway between the minimum and the maximum or equal to the average  — although each of those might be true in particular cases. If the data were 1 2 4 then neither condition is true. If the data were 1 2 3 both would be true.

Comment: The most common name for (minimum + maximum)/2 is _midrange_ and a different name is needed because the main idea is different from both the idea of the mean and that of the median.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s assume values to be on a continuum. (The problem gets annoying for technical reasons if we do not assume this.)

Then percentile $1$ is the smallest number such that $1\%$ of values are below.

Then in general, percentile $p$ is the smallest number such that $p\%$ of the values are below.